# Three.js change from mouseMove to randomly moving around

Tags: javascript, three.js

I got this website with a bg that as you move you mouse around it lights up part of the bg depending on where your mouse it. I was wondering if there was a way to make that light spot bob around on its own. Here is a codepen with the JS: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/MGoxNr

I hope thats enough to see what its doing

Here is a live website using this: http://www.crimson-moon.com/
If you need to see it.

```
function onDocumentMouseMove(event) {
mouseX = ( event.clientX - windowHalfX ) * 10;
mouseY = ( event.clientY - windowHalfY ) * -10;
}
```

Comment: Your codepen doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Remove `onDocumentMouseMove` and set some interval, where you set X, Y on circle with some radius. Set some incrementing varible, and depending on it, calculate X,Y position on circle.

x0, y0 - center of circle
r - circle radius
a - angle

```
x = x0 + r*cos(a)
y = y0 + r*sin(a)
```

changing angle x, y will change.

Comment: Any idea on what i should add. I dont know much if anything about three.js i got a book and the internet. thanks

Comment: You just need to know how to calculate position x,y on circle.

Comment: What should onDocumentMouseMove be changed to

Comment: if you want to remove mouse interaction, you should remove this listener.